# Attempt at title... Spawning movie clips according to X/Y axis of mouse AND changing each MC copies' frame position

Tags: actionscript-3

This is hard to explain.

My aim is to spawn sheep(symbol) each time i click placed according to the mouse's X/Y axis... . I want it to spawn copies of the sheep BUT i also want each copy to be a different image.. (each time the mouse is clicked, it will change the image inside the sheep's symbol (placed on different frames).

If anyone can help I will appreciate it so much!

This is the code:

```
stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, makeABox);


var i:Number = 1;


function makeABox(e:Event):void {

    var newSheep:myMC = new myMC();

    addChild(newSheep);

    newSheep.x = stage.mouseX;

    newSheep.y = stage.mouseY;

    i++;

}



var numPressed:Number = 0;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, countUp);

function countUp(evt:MouseEvent):void {
numPressed++;


if (numPressed == 1) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

else if (numPressed == 2) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

else if (numPressed == 3) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(3);
}

else if (numPressed == 4) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(4);
}

else if (numPressed == 5) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

else if (numPressed == 6) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(6);
}

else if (numPressed == 7) {
    sheep.gotoAndPlay(7);
}

if(numPressed >= 7) numPressed = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the code you posted in your question with this:

```
stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, addSheep);

var sheepCounter:int = 1;

function addSheep(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //create new sheep
    var newSheep:myMC = new myMC();
    //position it at mouse click
    newSheep.x = stage.mouseX;
    newSheep.y = stage.mouseY;
    //set frame of sheep to display
    newSheep.gotoAndStop(sheepCounter);
    //add sheep to display list
    addChild(newSheep);
    //update counter
    sheepCounter++;
    if (sheepCounter==8)
    {
        sheepCounter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure i follow. i tried adding this. it records the number of times i click and for each spawned sheep i want a new sheep to appear. when i put this code in, it seemed to only change the 2nd sheep spawned but kept the rest the same (on frame 1). Thanks by the way :)

Comment: not sure i follow you either ;). Can you explain what you are trying to achieve more clearly. What exactly should happen when user clicks on stage?

Comment: sorry. so the theme is counting sheep.. i have a sheep symbol with 7 sheep images inside, all on different frames with stop(); above each (so i can jump to these different images). The idea is that the user can click on the stage and a sheep will appear and stay at the location of the click. on the 2nd time i click, i want it to spawn the 2nd image inside the sheep symbol (by jumping to frame 2)... and this applies for the 3rd time 4th time etc... so it will end up being a collage of different sheep. does that make sense? :/

Comment: thanks. if i understand correctly, the first time user clicks on stage, a sheep (showing its 1st frame) is added. Second click adds sheep showing its 2nd frame. And so on until 8th click which adds sheep showing 1st frame again. Ive updated my answer